# Error installing Cordova using NodeJs on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

[image: The Snapshot of Error]

Error installing Cordova using NodeJs on Windows 7
Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run the command line as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation command is wrong!
It is

> npm install -g cordova

not

> npm -g install cordova

You must run cmd as administrator. If problem persist then install node and npm again.

or clean npm cache by `npm cache clean` command

**NOTE : you must have an active internet connection!**